# create scroll bar within list box

Tags: html, css, struts-1

I have the drop down list created using Struts html tags. When user clicks on the list, 3 different dates are shown in the list so that user can select any one from them. Now I want to display 20 different dates in the **drop down list with scroll bar**, so that the user can scroll the list box. Please suggest what are the modifications to be done for my below code to **display scroll bar within `<html:select>`**.
Below is my code to display dropdown list:

```
<html:select name="loanForm" property="loanPayDateStr" styleId="loanPayDateStr" tabindex="1" title="Select Date">
  <html:options property="monthValue" labelProperty="months"/>
</html:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will automatically add a scrollbar to your drop down list if the number of options is greater than the size of the list. If you want to display 5 options for example you'd add the size attribute to your select

```
<select size="5">
```

and if you had 10 options in the select you would be able to scroll to see options past the first 5.